# Match Alphanumeric Characters Not Inside a String

Tags: regex

I want to match all alphanumeric characters which is Not inside a Strings. All the outside ones.

`\w+` This will match all alphanumeric characters also `^\w+$` will match all alphanumeric characters inside a string how to match only outside ones?

Comment: I'm not sure my definition of string is the same as yours. Can you give any examples of what should and shouldn't match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((?:\"[^\"]\")*(?:[^A-Za-z0-9]*)([A-Za-z0-9]*))*
```

The first two `(?:)` should get rid of all text inside double quotes or with non alphanumeric text. The inner `()` should get alphanumeric characters not inside double quotes.

Note, I am assuming that `(?:)` is non capturing version of `()`.

Comment: it works, but when i have more complex scenario that to skip alphanumeric characters inside //  or /*  */ (commented) lines any idea to do it?

Comment: For `/* and */` you can probably try and adapt this:
`((?:\"[^\"]\")*(?:/\*(?:[^*]|*[^/]))*(?:[^A-Za-z0-9]*)([A-Za-z0-9]*))*`

For // you need to use some form of a multiline regexp, which i'm not familiar with.